# Take a picture using the device's user-facing camera using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to take a picture using the device's user-facing camera "Not browsing from device" using javascript or jquery.
I know the html code is:

```
<input id="q1" type="file" name="image" accept="image/*" capture="user">
```

I need to add accept and capture attributes using jquery or javascript  not in html code, I tried the following but it is not working:

```
$('#q1').prop("accept","image/*");
$('#q1').prop("capture","user");
```

Comment: Have you tried `$('#q1').attr(...` instead of `prop`?

Comment: @DeanTaylor Yes I tried but also not working.

Comment: What device are you testing on? You know it has limited device / browser support right? https://caniuse.com/html-media-capture

Comment: I try in ios and android devices, no i think that it working in all devices.

Comment: Put together a complete sample showing static HTML that works and the dynamic HTML (built using your jQuery) that doesn't so it can be reviewed. Edit your question  to include the sample - perhaps use codepen.io, jsfiddle.net or something similar.